# Creating a gallery with the Ribbon (Visual Designer) in VSTO

Tags: vsto, ribbon

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out and haven't had any luck so far:

I'm trying to replicate the Symbols dropdown menu (on the insert tab of the Word ribbon) with a list of custom symbols in a ribbon I'm building with VSTO.

As I'm brand new to coding, I've been trying to build this part with the Ribbon (Visual Designer).

I've added a menu button into the ribbon and inserted a gallery to the menu. I was planning on adding all of the buttons within the gallery (again, trying to replicate the "Symbols" dropdown). However, no matter what I change in the "properties" pane, I'm not having any luck: regardless of what I change in the properties, the little "gallery1" icon doesn't change at all. I've thoroughly researched this topic but haven't been able to find any helpful sources.

Does anyone have any advice on this? Thank you in advance.

-lc43

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you've tried... The Symbols gallery in Word is a Gallery control in a Group on the Ribbon - it's not in a menu. To get a selection of images for the gallery, use the `Items` entry in the Properties pane for the gallery control (it will display **(Collection)** with a little `...` button you need to click). In the dialog box you can then add items at the left and change their properties on the right, including adding an image. You won't see any of this in the Designer - you need to F5 (run the VSTO project) in order to view the result.

Comment: Cindy, thank you so much! This answers my question perfectly. I incorrectly thought that the Symbols editor consisted of a menu that dropped down into a gallery, rather than just a gallery itself (so what I was doing kept giving me a dropdown within a dropdown, rather than just the single dropdown I wanted). A couple other websites had led me astray into thinking this was the correct approach.

Changing the item on the ribbon into a gallery, rather than a menu, gave me the outcome I wanted. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Because you're new to Stack Overflow: The site's goal is to be a Q&A repository. I've marked this Q to be closed (and eventually removed if four more people agree with my assessment) as "can no longer reproduce the problem" since it's really a question that will help others, in the future (IMO). This is just to let you know how the site works - no problem or negative reflection on you or the question :-)

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks for the information on how this all works. :-)